# MobaXTerm jumps to next tab when pressing CTRL

Tags: mobaxterm

I have the problem, that I every time I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> MobaXTerm jumps to the next tab, although the keyboard shortcut is set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

This makes it difficult to use shells, since the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is frequently used, e.g. for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Does anybody have the same problem and knows how to fix this?

Comment: I always thought that this is due to my usage of "Neo-Layout" (a keyboard layout using autohotkey). Do you perchance also use Neo?

Comment: No, I use QWERTZ layout.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour started to occur on both my right and left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. And somehow I could turn this behaviour off by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button is on the left of my right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).